# Modeling Instances from a schema in OWL

Tags: xsd, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I am using Protégé to model a superclass **Item** with a subclass **Layer** and its child **Feature Service**. I want to model an instance of a Feature Service called **Address Layer** based on an existing XSD schema ([INSPIRE](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/ad/3.0/Addresses.xsd)). In this case, I would like to model the mandatory fields based on their data type. My objective is to define an **Address Layer** that has fields for: city (string), a state (string), a county (string), a country (string), etc. The goal is interoperability, where address feature layers from different providers can be harmonized.

1. Should I model the **Address Layer** as an individual instance of **Feature Layer** and then assert its data properties? (below)

[image: Individuals]

2. Or should I model a subclass of **Feature Service** called **Address Layer** and assert the data properties with respect to the domain?

[image: DataProperties]

3. Or other...? What is the best approach?

Also, is there a way to capture the rich semantics of existing schemas directly in Protégé from their xsds? Many thanks!

Comment: Are there multiple Adress Layers? If so, you should use the 2. option.

Comment: I also think that option 2 is the best and I've settled on that for now. Thanks!